# Countdown from 100 to the number (N) and separate even and odd numbers. Show even numbers in the first line and odd numbers in the second line

Tags: javascript, countdown

```html
<div id="counter">100</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var person = prompt("Please enter One number (N) where (N) is a positive integer.", "");
        if (person != null) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
                "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
        }
    }
    function countdown() {
        var i = document.getElementById('counter');
        i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML) - 1;
        if (parseInt(i.innerHTML) == 95) {
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }
    }
    var timerId = setInterval(function () { countdown(); }, 1000);
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Example Test Cases:

```
Input: 10      

Output:  
100 98 96 94 92
99 97 95 93 91
```

Another one:

```
Input: 5  

Output:
100 98 96     
99 97
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a possible solution, without many changes to your original code:

```html
<div id="counter">100</div>
    <p id="results"></p>
      <script>
    
    var input = parseInt(prompt("Please enter One number (N) where (N) is a positive integer.", ""));
    var half = parseInt(input / 2);
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    var res = document.getElementById('results');
    res.innerHTML += "Even: ";
    
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML) % 2 == 0) {
      res.innerHTML += i.innerHTML;
      input--;
    }
        
    function countdown() {
        if (input == 0) {
           clearInterval(timerId);
           return;
        }
        
        if (input == half) {
          var newValue;
          if (input % 2) {
            newValue = parseInt(i.innerHTML) + input * 2 - 3;   
          }
          else {    
            newValue = parseInt(i.innerHTML) + input * 2 - 1;   
          }
          i.innerHTML = newValue;
          res.innerHTML += "</br> Odd: ";
        }
        else {
          i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML) - 2;
        }
        
        res.innerHTML += " " + i.innerHTML;
    
        input--;
    }
    
    var timerId = setInterval(function(){ countdown(); }, 1000);
    
    
      </script>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Basically you decrease it by 2 till you reach the half, then you go back to the start - 1, looping through the odd numbers (or even, if the counter value was odd at first).

Answer (score 0):

I have made my own script which counts down from 100-0, and places each number into an Array variable depending on whether it's Odd/Even.

Here it is:

```js
var even = [];
var odd = [];

var number = 100;

changeNumber();
function changeNumber() {
    document.getElementById("counter").innerText = number;
    if (checkParity(number) == "even") {
        console.log("even");
        even.push(number);
    } else {
        console.log("odd");
        odd.push(number);
    }
    if (number == 0) {
        console.log("[Finished]"); 
        console.log("Even numbers:");
        console.log(even);
        console.log("Odd numbers:");
        console.log(odd);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            number--;
            changeNumber();
        }, 100);
    }
}

function checkParity(n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return "even"
    } else {
        return "odd"
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="counter">100</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that can help.

```js
(function () {
    const input = prompt("Please enter One number (N) where (N) is a positive integer.", "");
    let count = 100;

    if (isNaN(input) || input < 1) return;

    const inerval = setInterval(() => {
        count--;

        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            console.log('This is even Numbers ' + count);
        } else {
            console.log('This is odd Numbers ' + count);
        }

        if (input == count) return clearInterval(inerval);
    }, 1000);
})();
```